# Are there any internal MySQL protocol other than SQL queries in text?

Tags: mysql, sql, protocols

I was wondering what happens after MySQL received SQL texts? Hows does it process them across differents nodes?

Is it possible to create a driver which use binary MySQL protocols, rather than plain text SQL queries?

For example, direct access to tables data before `JOIN` or any other transformations.

Just a bit curious, not real-world problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now MySQL 5.6 has memcached protocol, you can write data in memcached protocol, and analye them in SQL. It's kinda cool.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/news-5-6-6.html

Comment: you answered your own question? this is kinda cool:). But to answer your question : MySQL protocol is documented, so read the good old manual.. MySQL is extensible and you of course can create your daemon plugin, listen on some port and receive queries and send replies in a protocol you want. memcached is an example of such plugin, handlersocket is another one.